# how to get anchorText of each URL in apache nutch for writing a new scoringFilter plugin?

Tags: apache, web-crawler, anchor, nutch, scoring

I am newbie to Apache Nutch so I spend a lot of time to search about it. **I need to get anchors of parent pages of each url in Apache Nutch**. I read about LinkDatum,LinkDB and Inlink that save data about each URL but I don't know exactly how to use these classes for adding a plugin for a new ScoringFilter.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the anchor text from the outlinks. `outlink.getToUrl()` gives the url as String and `outlink.getAnchor()` will gives the anchor text.